# Find the upper and lower limits, the supremum and infimum of {a_n} defined by

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

$a_{2n}=-\sqrt{2n}$; $a_{2n+1}$=$\sqrt{2n+1}-\sqrt{2n}$

Lower limit and infimum both negative infinity as $-\sqrt{2n}$ gets arbitrarily small.

Upper limit = zero ($a_{2n+1}$ goes to zero as $n-> \infty$), supremum = 1 (obtained for n = 0)

Is it right to my procedure?

Is there a more formal method?

Comment: The supremum is not at $n=0$. The sup of the sequence $(a_m)$ is reached at $m=1$. (Just a technicality!) For showing the upper limit, it would be more formally clear if you multiplied top and (missing) bottom by $\sqrt{2n+1}+\sqrt{2n}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The supremum is a maximum and, as André said, it is obtained at $\,m=1\,:\,\,a_1=\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}\,$ , since the function $\,f(x):=\sqrt{2x+1}-\sqrt{2x}\,$ is monotone descending.

The infimum certainly is $\,-\infty\,$, as $\,-\sqrt{2n}\to -\infty\,$ , and since this is also the limit of a subseq. of the seq. this is also the $\,\displaystyle{\underline{\lim}_{n\to\infty}a_n}\,$ .

Finally, $\,\displaystyle{\overline{\lim_{n\to\infty}}a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{2n+1}-\sqrt{2n}\right)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}+\sqrt{2n}}=0$

Comment: Why you can not take the succession from n = 0?

Comment: Of course you can, but that won't change the basic facts. Besides, sequences are usually indexed by the naturals which usually are considered to begin (at least wrt sequences) at 1...

Comment: @DonAntonio: Sequences are indexed from whatever point is convenient, and I’m not at all sure that $1$ is a more common starting point that $0$. The term *natural number* is ambiguous: for many of us it means the set of non-negative integers, **not** the set of positive integers.

Comment: Because the book says that the sup = 1

Comment: @Daniela Oh, I see...well, then yes: begin from $\,n=0\,$...:)

Comment: @Brian , I know that. I remarked that *usually* real/complex sequence are indexed from $n=1$ along the natural numbers. Of course, this doesn't mean ***always***.

Comment: @DonAntonio: I understood your statement. As I said, I’m not convinced that it’s true. And as a separate point, for me and many others, *indexed by the natural numbers* means starting from $0$, not $1$.

Comment: I believe that the sequence can start from 0 as long as it defined in the sequence

Comment: @Brian, We'll have to agree to disagree, and I won't post anymore on this. I just will direct you to Rudin's "Principles of Mathematical Analysis", definition 2.7, or chapter 26 in Spivak's "Calculus" , or to 1.1 in Lang's "Real and Functional Analysis", or definition 2.12 in Apostol's "Mathematical Analysis", or chapter 10.1 of Thomas's "Calculus", or chapter 11 of Swokowski's "Calculs with Analytic Geometry", to mention a few of the best well known books on the subject. In fact, I can't remember right now one single instance where the def. begins at n = 0 but, of course, there must be some.

Comment: @Daniela, of course it can. Nothing wrong or cumbersome about that.